# USB drives not working

Tags: usb, hardware-failure

I ran a diagnostic that said "USB port check failed"  Failure ID 6BV5UF-74981J-MFKR61-8D1U03

Is this fixable?  If not is there a way to attach a mouse to HDMI port???  Or convert HDMI port to USB to be able to use a mouse.

My son uses this computer to do Mine Craft, which apparently is much easier of you have a hand mouse.

Sorry it is an HP notebook. I went into the startup menu right at the beginning of set up. (I clicked esc then I clicked F2) & ran drivers. With the program I then put a mouse in while it was running diagnostic. Sorry I am definitely not a computer person & I am away from the computer now to check. & I did not know if it is showing or not.

Comment: Is the USB port showing up in device manager? or do you have no way to check since the port is not working??

Comment: What kind of computer is that? What kind of diagnostic did you ran? Please [edit] your question and add that information. HDMI is a video output, you can't convert it to USB unless it's a hybrid HDMI+USB port (unusual, but some laptops have it).